# How the ports really work?

Tags: mysql, networking, tcp, port

I'm bit confused with the concepts of ports. Lets say that I opened inbound port for `3306` (mysql) to `my-ip`. So `my-ip` will make a connection to `3306`. But I wonder in-turn how mysql speaks to my ip?

Say for example lets my application from `my-ip` is querying mysql, how mysql sends the data back to my `my-ip` machine? I mean it again uses port?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question basically amounts to "how does the internet work?" and is way too broad for SO. Start at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol maybe?

Comment: @Wooble: I know how the connection gets established. But my question is does mysql uses the same port to speaks back to my app?

Comment: I do not think it deserved the downvotes. It is a completely legitimate, if trivial, question.

Comment: Why people over here are downvoting my question? What is wrong in it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A TCP session is defined by 4 bits of information: a pair of IP addresses, and a pair of ports.

When you open a connection in firefox to `stackoverflow.com`, your operating system allocates an unused port to that connection. Usually something fairly high, say 32012. `stackoverflow.com` is listening on port 80, so no choice there.

The TCP session is therefore `you:32012 - stackoverflow.com:80`. This connection is used **bi-directionally**. So your HTTP requests are sent to `stackoverflow.com:80`, and the HTTP responses are sent to `you:32012`.

Comment: +1 thanks for replying.. So typically. The machine running `mysql` will send *outbounds* right?

Comment: As far as I know, no operating system makes a distinction between outbound and inbound ports. TCP sessions are attached to a local port, that session can be used to send **and** receive packets. This is what is generally called a **socket**. Multiple TCP sessions can be attached to the same local port (any number of people can be browsing stack overflow at once). In what context have you read about inbound vs outbound?

Comment: Oh I guess I confused with the concepts of firewall. In firewall I came across the words inbound and outbound..

Comment: Aha, what you're talking about there is "static network address translation"; SNAT, (more commonly just called 'port forwarding') If you want your sql database to be available to the outside world, you need to allow a TCP session to be created from the outside world. So you just need to create an 'inbound' rule, forwarding the mysql port to your database server. You shouldn't need any outbound rules - infact most routers just allow all outbound traffic by default.

Comment: Exactly. I'm confused with it. So I guess now I'm saying correct. In my firewall I can open the inbound for port `3306` for mysql. Upon the tcp connection, operating system will use any unwanted port for connection creation ( which is used for responses ). And since outbounds on all ports are allowed, this works right? And if I block all outbound's (just for an testing case), mysql doesn't work right?

Comment: Correct, if you block outbound packets, mysql wont work, nor will anything else - you wont be able to browse the internet from behind the router either. But you're still slightly wrong about the outbound connection, the connection is from server:mysql - outside:xxxxx and works in both directions, your server doesn't need to 'create a connection' as the client as already done that.

Comment: Cool thanks. And  my last question, since operating system uses the unwanted port for sending responses back, we can't predict and say block this outbound port `XXXX` right?

Comment: no, you dont know what port an incoming tcp session will originate from. blocking it would be useless as the client can just pick another one.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL's default port is `3306`, if you told it to connect to another port it would, otherwise it would connect by default to `3306`.

Comment: If you told it to *listen at* another port it would, otherwise it would *listen* by default at 3306.

Comment: @EJP ? I'm talking about the client.

Comment: In that case I don't see how you've answered the question.

Comment: @EJP He asked how a MySQL *client* would connect back and send data to `my-ip`, does it use port? In which case I answered yes, it uses port `3306` by default.